# What does this mean - "If you look like your passport picture, you probably need the trip"?

Tags: phrases

Has it got anything to do with appearances in the passport photo?

Comment: Please add context to turn this into a real question.  Eg, source and context of sentence, appearance of photo, who said it to whom.  Questions lacking enough data to support answers may quickly be closed.

Comment: Sorry, but I just read this line as a status update on facebook and dropped down here.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is basically an *"Explain this joke to me"* kind of question. I can't see anything about it that depends on the use of English as such.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has to do with the way someone might look in a passport photo, because such photos typically portray the subject as being unhappy in some way.